# Blender UV Mapping Cylinder Splitting Map

Tags: texturing, uv

Okay, I've been at this for days. I've created a cylinder that I'm trying to map an image onto its inside. I've boolean out a second cylinder as well as boolean out one side so that one can see into its interior (think curved projection screen).

Everything goes great until I start the UV Mapping process. The second I UNWRAP it, my UV editor takes the cylinder and splits the UV map in two. The two UV face groups are actually inverted LEFT to RIGHT. Meaning, if I align them together and painstakingly join their edges, the image is reversed down the center.

How can one get this to not happen? My model is vertex perfect. No flaws. The boolean appears to do a great job. However, the UV mapping (seemingly) arbitrarily splits the cylinder in half and reverses its sides.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

I've watched all the coke cans I can take. No one seems to have a tutorial that starts from a cut cylinder.

Thanks for any help.
[image]

Comment: My problem was that I was accidentally selecting BOTH sides of my cylinder. Once I selected ONLY the facing faces, and projected via view, it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you have a solution to your question you should post it as an answer using the answer box below.